# pass image url as parameter and showing merge images

Tags: php

i write below code to show merged images.

Myimage.php

```
$image1=imagecreatefromjpeg('111.png');
$image2=imagecreatefromjpeg('112.png');
$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);

imagecopy($image2, $image1, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagecopy($image2, $image2, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagejpeg($image2,'1.png');
imagedestroy($image2);
```

Now i want to pass whole image url as parameter and show combined image

so what i want in page i call

```
<img src="Myimage.php?param1=url &param1= url">
```

how can i do it

Comment: You could just do something like `imagePage.php?imageid1=111&imageid2=112` and then reference `$_GET['imageid1']` and `$_GET['imageid2']` to get the numbers. I'm only passing the numbers and you could pass more like entire image name. Either way works. You would also want to validate the get params.

Comment: is that logical to keep url like <img src="Myimage.php?param1=url &param1= url">

Comment: it works. I would say that is logical. You just need to send a header like `header('content-type: image/png')` from your image so the browser knows it is a png img.. You could also url_rewrite the image if you didn't want to pass url parameters. Could rewrite to something like `/images/111/112/image.png` to map to your image file passing 111 and 112 in a way you could read it through $_GET.

Comment: yeah but url are too long like :http://172.16.3.91/mournewcs1/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/320x320/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/3/23.png'

Comment: too long by what standard? urls can be over 2000 characters long without problem.